# Accessing vertex Input in surf directly without vert's out parameter In Tessellation Shader

Tags: unity, tessellation, shaderlab

I can get the vertex Input in vertex shader as follows:

```
   o.worldPos = v.vertex.xyz;
```

But how do I get the worldPos directly without filling the out parameter in the vert function. Asking this because the shader is a DX11 Tessellation one and out parameter in vert function is not available at all.

basically I want Initialize my Input shader and pass It to surface shader In vertex shader.I can do It but It's different In Tessellation shader so I need to Accessing vertex position in surf directly without vert's out parameter.

```
Shader "Tessellation Sample" {
        Properties {
            _EdgeLength ("Edge length", Range(2,50)) = 15
            _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
            _DispTex ("Disp Texture", 2D) = "gray" {}
            _NormalMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
            _Displacement ("Displacement", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0.3
            _Color ("Color", color) = (1,1,1,0)
            _SpecColor ("Spec color", color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
        }
        SubShader {
            Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
            LOD 300

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf BlinnPhong addshadow fullforwardshadows vertex:disp tessellate:tessEdge nolightmap
            #pragma target 4.6
            #include "Tessellation.cginc"

            float _EdgeLength;

            float4 tessEdge (appdata_full v0, appdata_full v1, appdata_full v2)
            {
                return UnityEdgeLengthBasedTess (v0.vertex, v1.vertex, v2.vertex, _EdgeLength);
            }

            float _Displacement;


            struct Input {
                float4 position  : POSITION;
                float3 worldPos  : TEXCOORD2;   // Used to calculate the texture UVs and world view vector
                float4 proj0     : TEXCOORD3;   // Used for depth and reflection textures
                float4 proj1     : TEXCOORD4;   // Used for the refraction texture
            };

            void disp (inout appdata_full v, out Input o){
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
            o.worldPos = v.vertex.xyz;
            o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.proj0 = ComputeScreenPos(o.position);
            COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.proj0.z);

            o.proj1 = o.proj0;
            #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
            o.proj1.y = (o.position.w - o.position.y) * 0.5;
            #endif
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _NormalMap;
            fixed4 _Color;

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
                o.Albedo = float3(0,0,0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
        FallBack "Diffuse"
    }
```

but I have error:

```
Shader error in 'Tessellation Sample': 'disp': no matching 1 parameter function at line 173 (on d3d11)
```

Answer (score 1):

[It's a bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/missing-vertex-function-overload-when-using-tesselation-function-in-surface-shader)

For a workaround, have a look at [Post #13](https://forum.unity.com/threads/tesselation-with-custom-data-in-vertex-shader-compile-error.221671/#post-2911955)
The idea behind this is to use unused vertex attributes to pass your custom data through.